# Como puedo listar con GridView evitando duplicados?

Tags: c#, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas, mi problema es el siguiente. Estoy haciendo un sistema en el cual tengo que agregar Envases, y a su vez esos envases tienen materiales. Los datos al ser dados de alta son almacenados en una base de datos.
Opte por crear una tabla `"material"` que contiene el id del material y su nombre.
Los materiales son arena, sosa, cal y varios. Tambien tengo la tabla de `"envase"` que contiene los campos del envase. Luego opte por una tabla `EnvaseMaterial` que tiene el codigo de envase como `FK`, el id del material y el porcentaje utilizado.
Ahora. El problema es que si voy a listar en `GridView` obviamente va a quedar duplicado como ven en la imagen.
Lo que yo necesito es que se vea asi: `Envase, Precio, Peso, Arena, Sosa, Cal, Varios`, siendo el valor de cada material **SU PORCENTAJE**.
Podria crear el campo `arena, cal, sosa, varios` en la tabla `envaseMaterial` y asignarle los porcentajes en el codigo. Pero no parece factible la opcion ya que si agrego un nuevo material que haria? tiro toda la tabla para crear un nuevo campo? no se puede asi. Ademas me estaria olvidando de la tabla `"material"` que contenia id y nombre de material.

codigo:

```
public void CargarEnvasesAMostrar()
        {

            var e = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = e;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(e))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand command =
                        new SqlCommand(
                            "SELECT distinct t.nombre,t.precioEnvase,t.peso,ma.nombreMaterial,e.porcentajeUtilizado FROM tipoEnvase t JOIN envaseMaterial e ON t.codigo=e.codigo join material ma on e.idMaterial = ma.idMaterial",
                            conn);
                    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
                    if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        gridEnvases.DataSource = dataSet;
                        gridEnvases.DataBind();
                    }
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    conn.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

GridView en code behind

```
            <asp:BoundField DataField="nombre" HeaderText="Envase"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="precioEnvase" HeaderText="Precio"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="peso" HeaderText="Peso"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="nombreMaterial" HeaderText="Material"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="porcentajeUtilizado" HeaderText="%"/>


        </columns>



          <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <sortedascendingcellstyle backcolor="#F7F7F7" />
         <sortedascendingheaderstyle backcolor="#4B4B4B" />
         <sorteddescendingcellstyle backcolor="#E5E5E5" />
         <sorteddescendingheaderstyle backcolor="#242121" />
     </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: tu intención es arreglar el query, conseguir un query nuevo, o arreglarlo del lado del programa? todo depende de la cantidad de datos, pero si, no tenes que crear otra tabla, tenes que arreglarlo con las que tenes.

Comment: mi intencion es que ese gridview en vez de mostar Envase, Precio,Peso,Material, %. Pase a mostrar Envase,Precio,Peso,Arena,Sosa,Cal,Varios y que los valores de arena,sosa,cal y varios sean esos %.

Comment: si perfecto, pero con que metodo?? porque hasta podrias construir la tabla a mano

Comment: la verdad que no sabría, si puedes explicarme que es lo que harias tu

Comment: aplanar el query puede ser mas penoso que armar la tabla a mano.. todo depende de la cantidad de datos.. y de que probabilidades hay de que se agreguen nuevos materiales, y como piensas mostrarlos en el futuro. no hay una solucion valida.. te recomendaria que explores un poco porque lado te gustaria ir..

Comment: convengamos que los materiales siempre fuesen los mismos sin posibilidad de agregar uno nuevo

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo resolvería modificando el query trasponiendo filas a columnas. Te dejo un link donde muestran ejemplos bun buenos usando pivot y sql dinamico en sql server:

[PIVOT - SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/multiples-opciones-para-transponer-filas-en-columnas)